# I want to display results outside of the function

Tags: php

I want to display results outside of the function
By sending the discount value outside the function

```
<?php
function product_discount($price)
{
  if($price<5000)
  {
    $dis=$price*5/100;
  }
  else
  {
    $dis=$price*10/100;
  }

  $total=$price-$dis;

  echo "ส่วนลดที่ได้::". $dis."บาท"."</br>";
  echo "ราคาสุทธิ::". $total."บาท"."</br>";
}

$price1=product_discount(1000);
$price2=product_discount(5000);
?>
```

Comment: can you explain better you issue and the desire result .

Comment: You know about the [return](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) keyword?

Comment: I want to show the discount and the net price outside of the function.

Comment: you could use return instead of echo like this ```return $dis;```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function product_discount($price)
{
  if($price<5000)
  {
    $dis=$price*5/100;
  }
  else
  {
    $dis=$price*10/100;
  }

  return $dis;
  
}
$price = 5000;
$discount = product_discount($price);
$total = $price-$discount;
  echo "ส่วนลดที่ได้::". $discount."บาท"."</br>";
  echo "ราคาสุทธิ::". $total."บาท"."</br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A function can only return 1 variable.
If you want to return multiple values ​​from a function, you can use an array.

```
function product_discount($price):array
{
  if($price<5000)
  {
    $dis=$price*5/100;
  }
  else
  {
    $dis=$price*10/100;
  }

  $total=$price-$dis;
  
  return ['dis' => $dis, 'total' => $total];
}

$arr = product_discount(1000);

echo "dis:". $arr['dis']."</br>";
echo "total:". $arr['total']."</br>";

// alternatively
$price2 = product_discount(5000)['total'];
```